# Error msg from psql incomprehensible

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm trying to run a function but it doesn't work.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/developer/PycharmProjects/credorax-git/project/services/pgw_credorax/credorax_tests.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_successful_refund (__main__.CredoraxTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/PycharmProjects/credorax-git/project/services/pgw_credorax/credorax_tests.py", line 51, in test_successful_refund
    [ 100, response['response_id'],  response['auth_code'],response['payment_ref'],  ])
ProgrammingError: column "trans_id" of relation "credorax_msgs" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO credorax_msgs (trans_id, response_id, auth_code,...
                                   ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO credorax_msgs (trans_id, response_id, auth_code, payment_ref) VALUES (_trans_id,_response_id,_auth_code,_payment_ref)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function insert_credorax_msg(integer,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 3 at SQL statement


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.465s

FAILED (errors=1)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

But the error is faulty, I actually do have a column named `trans_id` .

What is this about? My function looks like the following.

```
-- Function: public.insert_credorax_msg(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.insert_credorax_msg(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_credorax_msg(
    _trans_id integer,
    _response_id character varying,
    _auth_code character varying,
    _payment_ref character varying)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO credorax_msgs (trans_id, response_id, auth_code, payment_ref) VALUES (_trans_id,_response_id,_auth_code,_payment_ref);
RETURN true;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.insert_credorax_msg(integer, character varying, character varying, character varying)
  OWNER TO pgw;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are connecting to the right database when testing.

Usually test runners use a different configuration for database connection than the one you use for development or production.